# Why does column-count break bootstrap?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, column-count

I want to merge this layout with bootstrap:

https://jsfiddle.net/clankill3r/j9hj8rw8/

[image]

(here the columns are balanced nice without gaps, something I can't get done with bootstrap (maybe it is possible, if so let me know).

The problem now is that as soon as I start using column-count, the layout seems to break.

```
.foo {
  -webkit-column-count: 3; Chrome, Safari, Opera
  -moz-column-count: 3; Firefox
  column-count: 3;
}
```

(check right side of image)
[image]

Why does that happen?

https://jsfiddle.net/clankill3r/t528eozd/4/

Comment: Unsure if this is contributing to it, but the "Chrome, Safari, Opera" etc. is outside of comments, so it's interrupting the code. Make sure it's prefixed with `/*` and affixed with `*/`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding the following to .foo, after the column-count rules.

```
.foo {
  …
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You must specify the width of the column in mobile size. You have `content col-lg-8` class, so you can add the `col-xs-12` class.

```
<div class="content col-xs-12 col-lg-8">
    <div class="foo">
    [...]
    </div>
</div>
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/t528eozd/7/)